# SCNLookAtConstraint && SCNDistanceConstraint

Tags: swift, constraints, scenekit

Running on iOS16

Trying to get a better handle on SCNLookATConstraints, but struggling to get them to work in this demo app.

When I tap on the scene the box moves, but the camera doesn't follow it.

```
import SwiftUI
import SceneKit
import Combine

let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
let screenWidth: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
let screenHeight: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.height

let push = PassthroughSubject<Float,Never>()
var pusher: AnyCancellable!

struct CoreView: View {
 @State var scene = SCNScene()
 @State var place:Float = 0.0

 var body: some View {
    CustomSceneView(scene: scene, options: [])
        .frame(width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)
        .onTapGesture {
            place += 0.1
            push.send(place)
        }
 }
}

struct ContentView: View {
 var body: some View {
    CoreView()
 }
}

struct CustomSceneView: UIViewRepresentable {

var scene: SCNScene
var options: [Any]
var delegate: SCNRenderer!

var view = SCNView()

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> SCNView {

    view.scene = scene
    view.allowsCameraControl = true
    view.autoenablesDefaultLighting = false
    
    let cubeGeometry = SCNBox(width: 0.1, height: 0.1, length: 0.1, chamferRadius: 0)
    cubeGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
    let cubeNode = SCNNode(geometry: cubeGeometry)
    cubeNode.name = "cubeNode"
    cubeNode.simdPosition = SIMD3(0,0,0)
    
    let camera = SCNCamera()
    camera.fieldOfView = 60.0
    camera.focalLength = 100.0
    camera.sensorHeight = 0.0
    camera.wantsDepthOfField = true
    camera.focusDistance = 0.8
    camera.fStop = 5.6
    camera.wantsHDR = false
    camera.apertureBladeCount = 4
    camera.motionBlurIntensity = 1.0
    
    camera.name = "camera"
    
    let cameraNode = SCNNode()
    cameraNode.camera = camera
    cameraNode.name = "cameraNode"
    
    let lookAtConstraint = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: cubeNode)
    lookAtConstraint.influenceFactor = 1.0
    lookAtConstraint.isGimbalLockEnabled = true


    
    view.delegate = context.coordinator
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
    
    view.pointOfView = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "cameraNode", recursively: true)
    view.pointOfView?.simdPosition = SIMD3<Float>(0, 0.0, 2)
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cubeNode)
    
    view.defaultCameraController.interactionMode = .fly
    view.defaultCameraController.inertiaEnabled = true
    //view.defaultCameraController.maximumVerticalAngle = 45
    view.allowsCameraControl = true
    
    pusher = push.debounce(for: .seconds(0.5), scheduler: RunLoop.main)
        .throttle(for: 0.01, scheduler: RunLoop.main, latest: true)
        .sink(receiveValue: { [self] distance in
            cubeNode.simdPosition = SIMD3(distance,0,0)
        })
    
    return view
    
}

func updateUIView(_ view: SCNView, context: Context) {
    print("update")
    
}

func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator(view)
}
}

class Coordinator: NSObject, SCNSceneRendererDelegate {
private let view: SCNView
private var cubeNode: SCNNode!
private var cameraNode: SCNNode!

init(_ view: SCNView) {
    self.view = view
    super.init()
}

func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
    
    cameraNode = renderer.scene?.rootNode.childNode(withName: "cameraNode", recursively: true)
    cubeNode = renderer.scene?.rootNode.childNode(withName: "cubeNode", recursively: true)
    
    print("cubeNode \(cubeNode)")
    print("cameraNode \(cameraNode)")
    
    if cubeNode != nil && cameraNode != nil {
        let distanceConstraint = SCNDistanceConstraint(target: cubeNode)
        distanceConstraint.minimumDistance = 1
        distanceConstraint.maximumDistance = 2
        
        let lookAtConstraint = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: cubeNode)
        lookAtConstraint.influenceFactor = 1.0
        lookAtConstraint.isGimbalLockEnabled = true
        cameraNode.constraints = [lookAtConstraint, distanceConstraint]
    }
}
}
```

Tried adding the camera constraints to the built, the coordinator and shown here the renderer. The code is seeing it, but ignoring it.

Tried moving the scene with my mouse and clicking on it to move it, neither work.

Comment: Solved it, view.allowsCameraControl = false